# How to make a Cordova application a library?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I have an application that is basically a launcher for a bunch of .apk's (for android) and .ipa's (for iOS). I can get my hands on the .apks' and .ipas' but not the source codes for the different application.

Some of those applications are hybrid cordova applications. How can I make an android and iOS library for a cordova application given that android does not compile the assets directory into libraries? Reference: [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

Comment: Can you please add more explanation to your question ?

Comment: I want to convert .apk to an android library. The caveat is the .apk file might be built from a cordova project. The same for .ipa file.

Comment: As far as i know, that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @HardikVaghani